# Function to retrieve a subset of rows coming from another function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a function in a Google Sheet that returns a handful of columns and two rows.  One of those rows contains column headings, which I would like to remove.

[image: Google Sheet]

Is there any way to wrap this function with another function so that I can keep only row 2, which has the data I need?

Comment: Have you tried the `INDEX()` formula?

Comment: Why don't you share a doc. This way perhaps I can alter the code....

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra `INDEX()` works great!!  `INDEX(callService("geocodingServices"), 2)`.  Please post that as an answer so that I may accept it.  I cannot share the document as my function returning data is script driven and tied to some internal APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use the `INDEX` formula for that. Leaving the third parameter blank, allows for a complete row to be shown:

```
 INDEX(reference, [row], [column])

 INDEX(callService("geocodingServices"), 2)
```

I couldn't help thinking about the *geocodingService* you use. This is also possible from within Google Apps Script. First I had to retrieve an address from the data you provided in you question:

### Code

```
function getReverse(lat, lng) {
  var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(lat, lng);
  var result = response.results[0];
  return result.formatted_address;
}
```

Based on this address I was able to obtain the lat. and lng.:

```
function getGeo(address) {
  var response = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);
  var result = response.results[0];
  return [[result.geometry.location.lat, result.geometry.location.lng]];
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[geocodingService](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TpM_Pym8xNPTWUgboq7Ii84N6RGveRbL5A7HG5y34RY/edit?usp=sharing)**